# What is this graph called?

Tags: statistics

I'm not sure what it's called.

**Update:**
It's from the [NED](http://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/cgi-bin/objsearch?objname=M83&extend=no&hconst=73&omegam=0.27&omegav=0.73&corr_z=1&out_csys=Equatorial&out_equinox=J2000.0&obj_sort=RA%20or%20Longitude&of=pre_text&zv_breaker=30000.0&list_limit=5&img_stamp=YES).

Also explain:

- The name of these 4 axes. I mean I guess Y and X are in the same position but what about the others?
- **The `LINE` being repeated along the bottom axis (presume thats the Y). Whats all that about? There's about 18 of them...**
- Each dot and its bar. I'm guessing its to show a range of results?

Also, the points with larger 'ranges' (if that's what they are - ranges), display either vertical or horizontal bars, but the points with smaller 'ranges' display both. Pretty basic point, but just to be sure, each point can have a range vertically and horizontally, right?

- What is the meaning of those points along the line? I mean, what's
  the relevance of the dot somewhere in the middle of the line if its a range?
  How do you determine where to put the dot? It seems to matter a lot... on those smaller ranges, the vertical bar and the horizontal bar intersect on the dot...what is the dot signifying.

[image: graph]

Comment: graph theory isn't really the right tag. I'd suggest something referencing statistics.

Comment: Where did you find this graph?  It's obviously output from some kind of apparatus.

Comment: @JHance Thanks, changed

Comment: @mweiss good point: http://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/cgi-bin/objsearch?objname=M83&extend=no&hconst=73&omegam=0.27&omegav=0.73&corr_z=1&out_csys=Equatorial&out_equinox=J2000.0&obj_sort=RA+or+Longitude&of=pre_text&zv_breaker=30000.0&list_limit=5&img_stamp=YES

Comment: Are you looking for the name of a curve which this data seems to be following? It seems to me that the right hand side looks like a Gaussian distribution.

Comment: @MarkB It is really is a simple question! It's the type of graph. Bar, line, scatter ect...

Comment: @Starkers Oh, in that case it's just a scatter plot. I'm not the best person to be answering this, so I won't put this as an answer, but the lines with the dots in them usually indicate error. The dot is the measured value, and the line (error bar) indicates the experimental uncertainty. For instance, if you measure the length of an object you might say it is 120cm $\pm$ 2cm.

Comment: The top and bottom axes appear to be the same thing, with different labels.  For example the bottom axis, labeled $\log \nu$ (Hz), has a tick mark labeled 8.  If $\log \nu = 8$ Hz then $\nu = 100,000,000$ Hz, or 100 MHz... which you can see is the label directly above that tick mark on the top axis.